# WPF Optional Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, option-type

I have an existing XAML file with some data templates in it. One of these datatemplate can be used in different situations. Therefore, I want to bind 1 of the properties only if a certain condition is true.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around the issue by creating another datatemplate that overrides the original. Thanks for your help.